# Display database query results in custom module

Tags: 8, database

I have a custom block and I'm able to update its content using #pre_render if I'm using basic text.

However I'm unable to print database query results using the same way. Below is my code.

```
function _maintenance_prerender(array $build) { 
$build['content']['#markup'] = myDatabaseQuery();
return $build;
}

function myDatabaseQuery() {
  $query = \Drupal::database()->select('menu_link_content_data', 'm');
  $query->condition('m.title', 'Visit');
  $results = $query->execute();
}
```

Is there a special way to print database query results on a custom block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to exploit your result, you should fetch your result with one of the function of the [Statement class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Statement.php/class/Statement/8.6.x).

If you use the function fetchAll() for example, you will have an array of objects with all your result.

```
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

You can do a function to create your markup with that array.

You can also not use a function from Statement and do a foreach directly on the result generate by the execute() function to create your markup

```
$results = $query->execute();

foreach($results as $res) {
    $markup .= "<tr><td>$res->field_1</td><td>$res->field_2</td></tr>";
}
```

If you want see how is design your array, you can install the module kint (from the devel module) and display your result with

```
ksm($results);
```

Additionnally, to work, your query should have the list of fields it should select.

```
$query->fields('m', ['field_1', 'field_2']);
```